# No Controller found in test page

Tags: lightning, controller

I have seen the error regarding questions posted for the patch: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008jMrQAI. However, On deploying my Apex classes and lightning components on my test org. I get the same issue.

```
org.auraframework.throwable.quickfix.DefinitionNotFoundException: No CONTROLLER named js://c.CustomComponent found
            at 
org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.getHelper(AuraLinker.java:325)
            at 
org.auraframework.impl.linker.AuraLinker.linkDefinition(AuraLinker.java:174)
```

Everything works in the developer organization and I can also see the Lightning component on the dev console in the test org. I can open and see that the file is correct. Is there something that I am missing or am I unlucky and hitting this error again?

Any help would be great, 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this problem when the org that I pushed pushed the code into did *not* have a custom domain setup. See e.g. [Enable My Domain To Use Lightning Components](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_lightning_cruc.htm).

If you launch the Lightning App Builder, it outputs a more explanatory error message for the components. (The message "No CONTROLLER named..." isn't very helpful for identifying the cause.)

Comment: Enabling the domain... This fixed the issue for us.